# Find the maximum ratio between the number of nodes in a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I wrote a class that defines some operations on binary trees. 
Now I have to add a method that returns a reference to the node (or to one of the nodes, if there are more than one) U such that the ratio between the number of nodes in the subtree of the root U (thus including the node itself) and height (+1) of the same is maximized.

So I have to add to the sum the value 1 for the leaves otherwise the ratio would be 1/0 = infinity: that is, the result would be any leaf (wrong).

The algorithm must be linear in the number of nodes, visiting the tree once.

Can I define a private class auxiliary in case I need it.

I do not know how to do, someone help me?

My code is this.

```
public class BinaryTree {

    protected class Node {

        protected Integer element;
        protected Node left;
        protected Node right;

        Node(int element) {
            this.element = element;
            left = right = null;
        }

        Node(int element, Node left, Node right) {
            this.element = element;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        boolean isLeaf() {
            return left == null && right == null;
        }

    } //end Node class

    public class NodeReference {
        private Node node;

        private NodeReference(Node node) {
            this.node = node;
        }

        public int getElement() {
            return node.element;
        }

        public void setElement(int e) {
            node.element = e;
        }
    } //end class NodeReference

    protected Node root;

    public BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
    }

    public void add(int element, String path) {
        //working properly
    }

    protected Node add(int elem, String path, Node node) {
        //working properly
    }

    public void printPreOrder() {
        //working properly
    }

    protected void printPreOrder(Node node) {
        //working properly
    }

    public int height() {
        //working properly
    }

    protected int height(Node node) {
        //working properly
    }

    public int sum() {
        //working properly
    }

    private int sum(Node node) {
        //working properly
    }

    public int size() {
        //working properly
    }

    private int size(Node node) {
        //working properly
    }

    public boolean search(int x) {
        //working properly
    }

    protected boolean search(int x, Node node) {
        //working properly
    }

    public boolean equalTo(BinaryTree t) {
        //working properly
    }

    public boolean equals(Object ob) {
        //working properly
    }

    protected boolean areEqual(Node node1, Node node2) {
        //working properly
    }

    public BinaryTree copy() {
        //working properly
    }

    protected Node copy(Node node) {
        //working properly
    }

    public NodeReference find(int x) {
        //working properly
    }

    private Node find(int x, Node nd) {
        //working properly
    }

    public boolean isCompletelyBalanced() {
        //working properly
    }

    private int isCompletelyBalanced(Node node) {
        //working properly
    }

    public boolean is1Balanced() {
        //working properly
    }

    private int is1Balanced(Node node) {
        //working properly
    }


    private class BoolNode {

        boolean found; 
        Node node;

        BoolNode(boolean found, Node node) {
            this.found = found;
            this.node = node;
        }
    }

    public boolean removeSubtree(int x) {
        //working properly
    }

    protected BoolNode removeSubtree(int x, Node node) {
        //working properly
    }

    public int maxElem() throws IllegalStateException {
        if(root == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Empty tree.");
        return maxElem(root);
    }

    private static int max3(int x, int y, int z) {
        return max(x, max(y, z));
    }

    private int maxElem(Node node) {
        int max = node.element;
        if(node.left != null)
            max = Math.max(max, maxElem(node.left));
        if(node.right != null)
            max = Math.max(max, maxElem(node.right));
        return max;
    }

    public NodeReference maxDescendantsHeightRatio() {
        //As I write this method?
    }

}
```

I started doing it this way:

```
public NodeReference maxDescendantsHeightRatio() {
    ArrayList<Node> list = iteratorPreOrder();
    ArrayList<NodeWithRatio> listRatio = new ArrayList<NodeWithRatio>();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int s = size();
        int h = height() + 1;
        int r = ratioScore(s, h);
        listRatio.add(new NodeWithRatio(this, r));
    }
    //sort the array list
    Collections.sort(listRatio, new Comparator<Point>() {
        public int compare(NodeWithRatio o1, NodeWithRatio o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.ratio, o2.ratio);
        }
    });
    //find max value in the list of node with ratio
    NodeWithRatio result = listRatio.get(listRatio.size() - 1); //gets the last item, largest for an ascending sort
    return result.node;
    //return null;
}

private int ratioScore(int size, int height) {
    return size / height;
}

private class NodeWithRatio {
    Node node;
    int ratio;

    public NodeWithRatio(Node n, int r) {
        node = n;
        ratio = r;
    }
} //end NodeWithRatio class

public ArrayList<Node> iteratorPreOrder()  {
    ArrayList<Node> templist = new ArrayList<Node>();
    preorder(root, templist);
    for(int i = 0; i < templist.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(templist.get(i).element);  
    return templist;
}  

private void preorder(Node node, ArrayList<Node> templist)  {
    if(node != null)  {
        templist.add(node); // adds to end of list.
        preorder(node.left, templist);
        preorder(node.right, templist);
    }
}

public int height() {
    if(isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return height(root);
}

protected int height(Node node) {
    return (node == null)? -1: 1 + Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right));
}

public int size() {
    if(isEmpty())
        return 0;
    return size(root);
}

private int size(Node node) {
    if(node == null)
        return 0;
    return size(node.left) + size(node.right) + 1;
}
```

I think it's the wrong piece of code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int s = size();
        int h = height() + 1;
        int r = ratioScore(s, h);
        listRatio.add(new NodeWithRatio(this, r));
    }
```

Since it is not recursive, but I do not know how to fix it ... 
Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: That's a lot of code. It's not very clear where you're stuck exactly.

Comment: Is this a fancy way of asking if a node is the root of a full subtree?

Comment: @SamDufel I'm sorry but I didn't understand what do you mean..

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out, the calculation of the ratio is a combination of the calculation of the size and height of the tree.

In order to find the max ratio in one pass over the nodes of the tree, we can use a recursive method that would calculate both the size and height of the tree. In order to calculate the ratio for a node, it's not enough to know the ratios of its two children - we need to know the size and height of the children's sub trees. For this purpose I'll return an array of two ints - the first is the size and the second the height.

```
public int[] ratio(Node node)
{
    int[] result = new int[2];
    int[0] = 0;
    int[1] = 0;
    if (node = null)
        return result;
    int[] leftRatio = ratio(node.left);
    int[] rightRatio = ratio(node.right);
    result[0] = leftRatio[0] + rightRatio[0] + 1; // current sub tree size
    result[1] = Math.max(leftRatio[1] + rightRatio[1]) + 1; // current sub tree height
    return result;
}
```

Now, if you want to find all the nodes with the highest ratio, you can add a static variable holding the current max ratio and another static variable holding the nodes having that max ratio (I know, it's ugly, but it works).

```
...
static float maxRatio = 0;
static Set<Node> maxRatioNodes = new Set<Node>();
...
public int[] ratio(Node node)
{
    int[] result = new int[2];
    int[0] = 0;
    int[1] = 0;
    if (node = null)
        return result;
    int[] leftRatio = ratio(node.left);
    int[] rightRatio = ratio(node.right);
    result[0] = leftRatio[0] + rightRatio[0] + 1; // current sub tree size
    result[1] = Math.max(leftRatio[1] + rightRatio[1]) + 1; // current sub tree height
    float currRatio = result[0]/result[1];
    if (currRatio > maxRatio) { // found a new max ratio
        maxRatio = currRatio;
        maxRatioNodes.clear();
        maxRatioNodes.add (node);
    } else if (currRatio == maxRatio) { //  node's ratio equals the current max ratio
        maxRatioNodes.add (node);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @user3808470 That's strange. I'm sure this is the correct approach. I may have some trivial bug hiding somewhere (I couldn't actually run it). Did you try it on small trees? I suggest you add debug prints to see what's going on.